# Are there any ways to select a child tag while hovering on parent tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

I'm trying to move up a child "div" tag while hovering on parent "div" tag, while the child contains an image.

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner>
        <img href="image.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

If I make the image a direct child of the parent div, on hovering, the image will change it's position that like it's running away from mouse, but after that the image will not be considered as hovered so it will come back to it's last position, after that it will be considered as hovered again and then again and all these happen when I just hovered the mouse on the div once.

But if I select the child div while selecting parent div:hover, I can move the child div while patent div 's position is not changed

Any ideas?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use "#outer:hover #inner" to select the inner child div while the parent is hovered. I included a little sample of it in action.

```css
#outer {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#inner {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#outer:hover #inner {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <img href="image.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner>
        <img href="image.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

To achieve what you are saying, you can use this css.

```
#outer:hover #inner {
/*your css for #inner while #outer is hovered*/
}
```

Comment: Just a note, referencing the id's uses # not the dot! So it would be #outer and #inner